# HTML element's bottom margin in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, margin

The `<html>` element doesn't have a bottom margin in Firefox (version 97.0.1):

```css
html {
  margin: 1em;
  background: green;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 1200px;
  background: tan;
}
```

Is it a bug?

Comment: Tested it and it's working on my Firefox. Maybe try using `margin: 1em !important;`

Comment: That's weird. It works using Chrome. perhaps it's just a small bug. You can have a play around it. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I vote for a bug

Answer (score -1):

Here, you should add the margin in the body and remove the margin from html.

```css
html {
  margin: 0;
  background: green;
}

body {
  margin: 1em;
  height: 1200px;
  background: tan;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Since the height of the body is more then screen size your margin bottom is going below view

```css
html {
  margin: 1em;
  background: green;
}

body {
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
  height: 1200px;
  background: tan;
}


----------
```